# Openshift permission denied for upload and changing directories through sftp in filezilla

Tags: ftp, openshift-online-2

I can't upload or change directory permission through sftp in filezilla; copying is fine though. I'm getting permission denied for this. Even through PuTTy sftp, sudo returns a permission denied. How do i get around to accessing files just so i can change the alias for phpMyAdmin?

I'm using the login details given by Openshift.

Comment: Are you trying to use SSH or SFTP to view and modify file contents? If you instead meant SSH please edit your question. If you're using SFTP, using SSH instead would give you a shell and allow you to sudo.

Answer (score 1):

Users of OpenShift Online do not have access to sudo.

Thought you can(this is 100% unsupported) copy https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/tree/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-phpmyadmin to its own git repo and add that as a custom cartridge instead of phpMyAdmin.

If you did that you can edit https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/cartridges/openshift-origin-cartridge-phpmyadmin/versions/shared/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf and change the alias.